# Substitute character in Makefile variable after evaluation

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that I'm using to build Docker containers. I'm detecting the current git branch and then using that as a tag for the build, but some git branches may contain slashes, which is an invalid character for Docker tags.

I'm trying to replace the slashes with a "-" within the Makefile, but I need to detect the git branch first. Here's a very simplified version of what I have:

```
NAME = foo
BRANCH = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
TAG = $(subst /,-,$(BRANCH))

build:
    docker build --tag=$(NAME):$(TAG) .
```

The issue is that if `BRANCH` ends up being set to "foo/bar" after detecting the git branch, then `TAG` also ends up being "foo/bar". However, if I explicitly set `BRANCH` to "foo/bar" (instead of detecting it), then `TAG` gets correctly set to "foo-bar", which is a valid tag.

I'm pretty new to Makefiles, but my guess is that the shell command is being evaluated too late, and the `subst` command is attempting to do the replacing on the shell command itself, and not on the result of the command.

I've also tried using the ":=" for immediate evaluation (if I understood the docs correctly):

```
BRANCH := `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

to no avail.

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting, or am I stuck having to pass in the branch name manually to the `make` command?

Comment: I think the `git` and `docker` tags of this question are not relevant, as it's purely `make` and `shell` related. Do you mind dropping them?

Comment: I added those tags in case someone doing something similar already had a solution to this problem. But sure, I'll remove them, I guess it must be cluttering your listings somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks are expanded by the shell, not make. The contents of your `$(BRANCH)` make variable is the literal string with the backticks in it. You can see this by adding `$(info BRANCH := $(BRANCH))` to your makefile.

So when your `$(subst)` call runs the slash in the branch name hasn't shown up yet and so can't get replaced.

Either do the substitution at recipe/shell time with `sed` or a substitution parameter expansion or use `$(shell)` in the make variable assignment to have make perform the `git` call.

```
BRANCH = $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

If you use `BRANCH` more than once in any given recipe then you may want to use a [simply-expanded variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) instead and use

```
BRANCH := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

but this will have make run that `git` command at make parse time regardless of whether or not anything actually being built needs it (but with the normal assignment make will run the `git` command once each time the `$(BRANCH)` variable is expanded).

Comment: Your last line perfectly explained the difference for me between "=" and ":=", where I felt the docs were a tad unclear, so thank you! I decided to run `$(shell <command>)` and that worked.